# How can I download a file from an S3 bucket with wget?

Tags: amazon-s3, https, wget, s3cmd

I can push some content to an S3 bucket with my credentials through S3cmd tool with s3cmd put contentfile S3://test_bucket/test_file

I am required to download the content from this bucket in other computers that don't have s3cmd installed on them, BUT they have wget installed.

when I try to download some content from my bucket with wget I get this:

```
 https://s3.amazonaws.com/test_bucket/test_file
--2013-08-14 18:17:40--  `https`://s3.amazonaws.com/test_bucket/test_file
Resolving s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)... [ip_here]
Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)|ip_here|:port... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
`2013`-08-14 18:17:40 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

I have manually made this bucket public through the Amazon AWS web console.

How can I download content from an S3 bucket with `wget` into a local txt file?

Comment: Note for others, I had to wrap my S3 URL in quotes for it to work. Otherwise, I got 403 Forbidden. e.g. `wget "https://s3.amazonaws.com/test_bucket/test_file"`. Our URLs are expiring and have some trickery in there to authenticate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got it ... If you upload a file in an S3 bucket with S3CMD with the --acl public flag then one shall be able to download the file from S3 with wget easily ...

Conclusion: In order to download with wget, first of one needs to upload the content in S3 with `s3cmd put --acl public --guess-mime-type <test_file> s3://test_bucket/test_file`

alternatively you can try:

```
s3cmd setacl --acl-public --guess-mime-type s3://test_bucket/test_file
```

notice the setacl flag above. THAT WILL set the file in s3 accessible publicly
then you can execute the `wget http://s3.amazonaws.com/test_bucket/test_file`

Answer (score 41):

You should be able to access it from a url created as follows:

`http://{bucket-name}.s3.amazonaws.com/<path-to-file>`

Now, say your s3 file path is:

`s3://test-bucket/test-folder/test-file.txt`

You should be able to wget this file with following url:

`http://test-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/test-folder/test-file.txt`

Comment: note that you are using a HTTP protocol and I am being given a HTTPS url from the amazon management console ... how does the HTTPS change things?

Answer (score 39):

1. Go to S3 console
2. Select your object
3. Click 'Object Actions'
4. Choose 'Download As'
5. Use your mouse right-click to 'Copy Link Address'
6. Then use the command:

   `wget --no-check-certificate --no-proxy 'http://your_bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/your-copied-link-address.jpg'`

Comment: Works great! No need to install s3cmd or other CLI :)

Comment: "HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden"

Answer (score 9):

AWS cli has a 'presign' command that one can use to get a temporary public URL to a private s3 resource.

```
aws s3 presign s3://private_resource
```

You can then use wget to download the resource using the presigned URL.

Comment: ERROR 403: Forbidden.

Comment: It works excellent!!! It gives me a http path that I can use in wget to resume download of the file. Thank you!!!

Comment: I also had the FORBIDDEN error last time I tried to use it. And found a much better way to do this using the `aws s3 cp` command, like I described in my answer (see above or below)

Answer (score 9):

I had the same situation for couple of  times. It’s the fastest and the easiest way to download any file from AWS using CLI is next command:

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket/dump.zip dump.zip
```

File downloaded way faster than via wget, at least if you are outside of US.

Comment: With my `AWS CLI credentials` activated, this worked perfectly for me.

Comment: this work only if you configure aws cli other wise it will not work.

Comment: where the files are saved? I ran the command successfully but I cannot find the files

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and I solved it by adding a Security Groups Inbound rule:

HTTPS type at port 443 to my IP address ( as I'm the only one accessing it ) for the subnet my instance was in.

Hope it helps anyone who forgot to include this

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do that is to disable **Block all public** firstly.

1. Hit **your bucket name** >> go to **Permissions** >> **Block public access** (bucket settings)
   [image]
2. If it is **on** >> hit **Edit** >> **Uncheck** the box, then click on **Save changes**
   [image]
3. Now hit the **object name** >> **Object action** >> **Make public using ACL** >> then confirm **Make public**
   [image]
4. After that, copy the **Object URL**, and proceed to download
   [image]

I hope it helps the future askers. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

incase you do not have access to install aws client on ur Linux machine try below method.

- got to the bucket and click on download as button. copy the link generated.
- execute command below

  wget --no-check-certificate --no-proxy  --user=username --ask-password -O  "download url"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the read permission has been given correctly.

If you do not want to enter any account/password, just by wget command without any password, make sure the permission is like the following setting shows.

By Amazon S3 -> Buckets -> Permisions - Edit
Check the Object for "Everyone (public access)" and save changes.[permission setting like this - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cf9bd.png)

or choose the objest and go to "Actions" -> "Make public", would do the same thing under permission settings.

Answer (score 0):

you have made the bucket public, you need to also make the object public.
also, the wget command doesn't work with the S3:// address, you need to find the object's URL in AWS web console.

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm too late to this post. But thought I'll add something no one mentioned here.

If you're creating a presigned s3 URL for wget, make sure you're running aws cli v2.
I ran into the same issue and realized s3 had this problem

```
Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4
```

This gets resolved once you presign on aws cli v2

Answer (score 0):

I had the same mistake

I did the following :

1. created IAM role > AWS Service type > AmazonS3FullAccess policy inside
2. applied this role to the EC2 instance
3. in the the Security Groups opened inbound HTTP and HTTPS to Anywhere-IPv4
4. made the S3 bucket public
5. profit! wget works! ✅